# Using uri (android.net.uri) as a link to get image from internet and put it in a ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-viewholder

I have a item object, containing a Uri variable called image. something like this

```
http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designcontest/vintage/256/Type-icon.png
```

I tried to get from the class method the Uri and use it for setting up the ImageView called Image in my viewholder

```
 viewHolder.Image.setImageURI(item.getImage());
```

but it didn't work, so I tried something more complex without success

```
        //Image
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(item.getImage().toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            viewHolder.Image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I have allowed internet permissions, and if I use some images from local with Uri.parse it works without any problem. 
Here's the error I get from logcat

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.net.URLConnection java.net.URL.openConnection()' on a null object reference
```

I think the problem is something in the url definiton but I'll ask you if someone had my same problem and how you solved. Thanks in advance!

Comment: your trying to open a connection on a null URL object, this causes a null pointer

Answer (score 0):

for this purpose try to use a specific image library like `Picasso`, `Glide` or `Fresco`. The first one is the simplest with nice fluent interface and it loads images pretty fast:

Please check it, as you may don't know it. Here is a short description taken from its official site (link below):

> Images add much-needed context and visual flair to Android
>   applications. Picasso allows for hassle-free image loading in your
>   application—often in one line of code!
>
> ```
> Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
> ```
>
> Many common pitfalls of image loading on Android are handled
>   automatically by Picasso:
>
> - Handling ImageView recycling and download cancelation in an adapter.
> - Complex image transformations with minimal memory use.
> - Automatic memory and disk caching.
>
> From: http://square.github.io/picasso/

As it already Open Source project you can check the code to improve it or make your own version fitted to your actual needs.

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood, `url = new URL(item.getImage().toString());` is throwing a `MalformedURLException`, which your catch block is suppressing. As a result, `url` is null, which is why you're getting a `NullPointerException`. A constructor can't return a null, so this is the only thing I can imagine.

Unless you really know what you're doing, I recommend you use a library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to do image fetching.